# Access json data using jquery for setting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, r, ajax

I bring data into `json` string which comes as `r.d` in my below code.

Now I want to access the field of it. so how should I access it ?

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
            url: "GET_DATA_BY_STORE.aspx/GETSTOREINFO",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ STORE_ID: STORE_ID }),
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (r) {                   
                alert(getJSONValue[0].STORE_ID);                    
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
               // alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
            }
        })
```

And in `r.d` I get data as

[image: T]

Comment: Have you tried to convert it in a json object? -->  JSON.parse(r.d)
Then you should be able to traverse the object using standard javascript properties access and read the fields

Comment: @revy: Yes, I tried like this `var jsondata = JSON.parse(r.d);` and in alert for (jsondata) I get as `[object object]` .So how could I will access its fields and values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have converted it as json object using [JSON.parse](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGgp3K66nXAhUJrxoKHQy_CWkQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fit%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AOvVaw27SxMBsxwtfxcyUwNZpC2N) you can access properties like you normally do with javascript objects:

```
var jsonString = '{"d": [{"field1": "value1", "field2": 15.0}, {"field3": [1,2,3]}]}'
var r = JSON.parse(jsonString)

console.log(r.d)
// output: [ { field1: 'value1', field2: 15 }, { field3: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]

console.log(r.d[0].field1)
// output: value1

console.log(r.d[0].field2)
// output: 15

console.log(r.d[1].field3)
// output: [ 1, 2, 3 ]


// you can also use brackets notation to access properties in object
console.log(r.d[0]["field1"])
// output: value1


// or you can iterate properties if the data type of a field is an array (r.d is an array)
r.d.forEach(function(prop) {
    console.log(prop);
})
// output:  { field1: 'value1', field2: 15 }
//          { field3: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

Comment: i tried like this ` var jsonString = r.d;
                    var r = JSON.parse(jsonString)
                    alert(r);    ` but still couldnt access the fields

Comment: Mine was just an example to show you how to access data in javascript after you have transformed the raw json in a json object. In your case you can show the first property of the first object in r.d like so:

alert(r.d[0]["RRSOC_ID"]) // should show 18